# How to check assumptions for Bayesian Linear Mixed Models in R?

Tags: r, bayesian

I'm trying to create a Bayesian mixed linear model for my master thesis but having trouble to check all assumptions (especially normality of errors)/ I'm not sure if I'm doing it right, because I'm an R/statistics noob.

My model looks like this:

```
mymodel <- stan_lmer(y ~ x + (1+x|z), data = mydata)
```

**What I found/tried (does this all make sense to you?):**

**Regarding linearity**

*visual*

```
plot(mydata$y, resid(mymodel))
```

*mathematical*

MISSING (is there even a way?)

**Regarding homoscedasticity:**

*visual*

```
plot(fitted(mymodel),resid(mymodel))
```

*mathematical*

```
mydata$residuals <- residuals(mymodel)
mydata$absresiduals <- abs(mydata$residuals)
mydata$residualssq <- mydata$absresiduals^2
LeveneModel <- lm(residualssq ~ x, data=mydata)
anova(LeveneModel)
```

**Regarding normality of errors:**

*visual*

```
plot(density(resid(mymodel)))
```

MISSING: Q-Q-PLOT; something like `qqmath()` would do for non-Bayesian models

*mathematical*

MISSING (is there even a way?)

**Regarding independence of errors:**

*mathematical*

```
durbinWatsonTest(residuals(mymodel))
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: The [bayesplot](http://mc-stan.org/bayesplot/) package provides tools for visualization and model checking after fitting a Bayesian model; see its [vignettes](http://mc-stan.org/bayesplot/articles/index.html). Take a look in particular at posterior predictive checks. You can do those with `rstanarm::pp_check`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bayesian modeling is different from frequentist modeling in many ways, one of the most important being that binary decisions (normal/non-normal; equal vs. unequal variances) are not required, and parameters can be added for things you don't know.  These extra parameters don't always require full degrees of freedom because we often use priors that favor smaller values for the extra parameters.  The result of adding extra parameters is that uncertainty intervals will be accurate, whereas in the traditional frequentist world if you assess residuals for normality or constant variance and make decisons from that the resulting confidence intervals will be falsely narrow.

An easy way to allow for non-normality is to use a $t$ distribution instead of Gaussian for residuals, and to include heteroscedasticity.  All this is quite easy with the R `brms` package.  Start with the [Bayesian $t$-test](https://hbiostat.org/bbr/htest#bayesian-t-test).

It appears that you are using the `rstanarm` package in R which is also excellent.  It may have options to limit assumptions as well.

Comment: In the Bayesian framework, model checking tends to focus on the convergence of MCMC chains and posterior predictive checks rather than the assumptions that are more familiar to users of frequentist statistics.

Comment: Well put.  Sometimes "large" (e.g., including a bunch of interactions) and "small" (no interactions) are compared, and sometimes models assuming different structures or residual distributions are compared in Bayes.  The big idea though is to specify a model for what you known and add parameters for what you don't, and to de-emphasize traditional model diagnostics.  [Semiparametric models](https://fharrell.com/post/rpo) play into this by allowing one to be distribution-free (either with Bayes or frequentist).